# Protractor: How to reach the second href?

Tags: jquery, href

```
<div class="divName">
  ...
  <a href="some url">some text</a>
  <a href="some url">another text</a>
  ...
</div>
```

I can reach the first href with `$('.divName a').click();` but how can i reach the second one?

Answer (score 3):

By using the .`all` method on `element`, you return an array of items, which you can then access. This avoids the need to add classes just so you pass the test. eg:

```
<div class="divName">
  ...
  <a href="some url">some text</a>
  <a href="some url">another text</a>
  ...
</div>
```

In protractor test:

```
var urls = element.all(by.css('.divName a'));

expect(urls.count()).toBe(2); //passes test
urls.get(1).click().then(function() { ... };
// access an item in array with the .get(index) method, 
// then follow the link with click() should you wish
```

There is also a shortcut method:

```
var urls = $$('.divName a');
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe adding some classes help you

```
<div class="divName">
   <a href="some url" class="first">some text</a>
   <a href="some url" class="second">another text</a>
</div> 
// jquery
$('.first').click();
$('.second').click();
```

or if your don't want to use class, use jquery [.eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)

```
$('.divName a').eq(1).click();  // trigger click event for second link
```

or [:eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)  selector

```
$('.divName a:eq(1)').click();  // trigger click event for second link
```

Answer (score 0):

You can "reach" the 1st one because the select `$('.divName a')` will return an array of objects, each will be a `href`.

You could use `[.next()][1]` but that's a bit flaky and unreliable. I'd apply IDs to the hrefs so you can bind to them permanently and reliably.

Answer (score 0):

or iterate:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.divName a').each(function (index, element) {
        alert($(element).attr('href'));
       // element.click();
    });
</script>
```